# On which bases Porges claims that mobilitization activation inhibits perception of positive social signals?

Tags: social-psychology, arousal

I'm reading Polivagal Theory by Stephen Porges. There Is one statement that is not entirely clear ( Sorry if Im not using proper technical terms but that book Is one of the few which is not in english among my books) to me.

At some point he claims that social engagement and motion activation (sport) are not compatibile and entering motion state inhibits detection of social engagement.

However I cannot connect that to other parts of the theory. While I believe a perceived state of danger may inhibits positive social signs detection, I cannot understand why also mobilization may prevent the same thing. That's sound like socialization Is harder when performing sports which is somewhat counter intuitive.